# Group list of item with same name and add values thean return all column

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i have the list of item from the Database as :

```
Category    ItemName    Quantity    Location
Commputing  Mouse         2          store1
Printer Zebra P4T         5         store2Bank5
Commputing  Mouse         4           store1
Printer     ZT zebra      2         store1Bank2
Printer     ZT zebra      1         store1Bank2
FarmTool    FieldBoot     12        Store1Floor2
FarmTool    FieldBoot     12        Store1Floor2
```

[2] so i want to have the result to sum items with same name as this :

```
Category    ItemName    Quantity    Location
Commputing  Mouse         6          store1
Printer Zebra P4T         5         store2Bank5
FarmTool    FieldBoot     24        Store1Floor2
Printer     ZT zebra      3         store1Bank2
```

I have the code as :

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = db.Items;
var da = items
            .GroupBy(d => d.ItemName)
            .Select(g => new {
                Key = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                Name = g.First().Location,
                ItemName = g.First().ItemName,
                Category = g.First().Category
                })
            .ToList();

return View();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following. Basically you use as the grouping key
both the `Category` and the `ItemName`.

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = db.Items;
var da = items.GroupBy(x=> new { x.Category, x.ItemName })
              .Select(g => new {
                Category = g.Key.Category, 
                ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                Location = g.First().Location}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very Helpful. so what should i pass to the view, will i have to do it as :  return View(da)